# how do you convert the selected list to a custom list in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two select boxes on html. Based on selected items, I need to convert the selected items to list 
like this:

```
c("item1", "item2", "item3")
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sean101/84zugx8p/3/)

```
$("#submitbutton").on("click", function(){


var jsonData=JSON.parse(    "[{\"id\":1,\"desc\":\"Date\"},{\"id\":2,\"desc\":\"CPU\"}]"
);

var $select = $('#yaxis');
                      $(jsonData).each(function (index, o) {    
                      var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.desc).text(o.desc);
                      $select.append($option);
                    });

                   var $select1 = $('#xaxis');
                      $(jsonData).each(function (index, o) {    
                      var $option1 = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.desc).text(o.desc);
                      $select1.append($option1);
                    });   
})

$("#selectitems").on("click", function(){
     var names=$("#xaxis").val();
      var names1=$("#yaxis").val();
      var param=names+","+names1;
    console.log(param);
})
```

submitbutton builds the selected boxes and selectitem needs to return selected items. For example, in the jsfiddle example, if I select CPU and Date, my param list should be like this:

```
console.log(param)
c("CPU","Date")
```

I tried something like this:

```
$("#selectitems").on("click", function(){
     var names=$("#xaxis").val();
      var names1=$("#yaxis").val();
      var param=names+","+names1;
    param="c("+param+")";
    param=param.split(",");
    console.log(param);

})
```

console.log(param), shows like this:

```
["c(DateTime", "CPU)"]
```

I need param output to be like this:

```
c("DateTime", "CPU")
```

updated [update jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sean101/84zugx8p/4/)

Comment: Instead of `JSON.parse()`, why don't you just use an object literal?

Comment: @royhowie, I am doing that to ilustrate, that part is working for me. I just need the ouput to c("CPU", "Date") format. I've update the post. But I really dont want to see the string wrapped around [], any ideas?

Comment: `c("item1", "item2", "item3")` is not a list, it's a function call. I have no idea what you're trying to get out this.

Comment: @lincolnk, based on the selected items, I need to format the param variable to be like that. It is not a function call. I will use output to call another function. That function expects arguments to be c("item1","item2","item3") etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want your click handler to be something more like this:

```js
$("#selectitems").on("click", function(){
   var values = [];
   $("#xaxis option:selected, #yaxis option:selected").each(function() {
     values.push('"' + $(this).text() + '"');
   });
   param="c(" + values.join(",") + ")";
   console.log(param);
})
```

[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84zugx8p/6/)

Comment: this is good, I will accept the answer. One little question. When I pass to another function, I see it passed as this exact form: "c(\"Date\",\"CPU\")"), is there a function in javascript that I will parse out \ ? just pass the values as c("Date","CPU") ?

Comment: This all really depends ultimately on what you're intending to do with this string value, but the backslashes simply mean that the string contains double quotes and it's escaping them with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to construct a list of arguments why not use [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)?

e.g.

```
$("#selectitems").on("click", function(){
     var selected = $("#xaxis option:selected, #yaxis option:selected").map(function() {
         return $(this).text();
     });
     c.apply(null,selected); 
});
```

Here is a fiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/84zugx8p/11/